# Uploading an image within Django working with a mysql database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to upload an image to a specific directory within my Django project using the upload_to='staticfiles/images' parameter within my models attribute. I have the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT specified in settings as well as the needed addition to my urls.py page as seen below.

Models.py

```
#upload_to='staticfiles/images'
image = models.ImageField(db_column='Image', upload_to='staticfiles/images', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'

if DEBUG:
  STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')]

else:
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My folder hierarchy looks like the following:

```
-> A5 (desktop folder)
    -> CC (django project)
        -> base (django application)
        -> staticfiles
            -> images
```

I am working with a mysql database and upon uploading the image, the image name gets successfully added to the image column within the database and everything works as it should, except for the image not being uploaded into the specific project directory folder I am specifying. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You set your `MEDIA_ROOT` as `/media`, the images will upload to media folder and as you set `upload_to = 'staticfiles/images'` the image should upload to `media/staticfiles/images`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already tried that and it does not work... I don't have a media folder that gets created.

Comment: Create a media folder first and then try

Comment: I made a separate folder in the same directory as base and called it "media" then made a "staticfiles" folder within, with an "images" folder within that, and I am still facing the same issue.